# Crontab new line just don't work as it should?

Tags: cron, vps

I have set crontab on every 24 hrs should run a single php command, instead it runs the command like 20+ times a day.  It doesn't work as it should. Is it really wrong?

```
* */12 * * * php /var/www/mything.php
```

I added this on new crontab line? Is the line correct?

Comment: That should run about 120 times a day - every minute of every twelfth hour. `*` means "every" or "all".

Answer (score 0):

```
0 */12 * * * php /var/www/mything.php
```

should run the command every 12 hours (0 and 12 o'clock)

```
0 12 * * * php /var/www/mything.php
```

should run the command at 12 o'clock every day